# В каком порядке следует писать условия между операторами AND?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Привет!

Вопрос касается оптимизации SQL-запросов.

Подскажите, В каком порядке следует писать условия между операторами AND? 
Сервер MSSQL 2005.

Comment: @Genniy, судя по Вашему комментарию Вы и сами все это знаете. Проведите эксперименты с MSSQL  и доложите сообществу. Все будут благодарны и возможно захотят обсудить результаты.

Comment: Я та конечно про это читал. Но на практике я не вижу результата и логики.
По идее нужно отбрасывать самый большой кусок изначально, но почему везде пишут, что следует по возростанию.

Comment: Приведите несколько конкретных примеров (SQL) в UPD к вопросу.

Comment: Честно говоря, не знаю, как в SQL сервере, но вообще нормальные люди всегда сортируют по нагрузке, к-рое дает условие (ибо в нормальном обработчике логики после первого false серия and'ов обламывается). То есть, если поле ID есть PRIMARY, то нелогично делать так: (mysql)

    SELECT * FROM table WHERE (`NAME` LIKE '%А%') AND (`ID`>20)

Ибо в этом случае проверка на наличие "А" в поле NAME пройдет по всей таблице.

Answer (score 1):

Если все операторы AND, то порядок не имеет значения - это примерно как умножение. В этом случае СУБД сама должна выбрать оптимальный план выполнения запроса.

Comment: А как там по поводу возрастания вероятности истинности условия...?

Answer (score 1):

Оптимизатор может менять порядок выполнения предикатов, пытаясь уменьшить размер промежуточной выборки. Я не знаю способа помешать ему в этом. Поэтому можете писать в любом порядке. :-) Ну и поддерживайте статистику в актуальном состоянии.